# Generic Method Error

Tags: c#

I am trying to do something like:

```
public DataObjectBase GetCurrentSettings<T>(string path) where T : DataObjectBase
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Path cannot be empty.");
        }

        return _currentSettings[T].Invoke(path);
    }
```

but it won't compile. How can I achieve this? I basically import an IEnumerable of classes that can manipulate my DataObjects using MEF and the importmany attribute. Then in the constructor I turn each operation into a keyed dictionary just so I don't have to run the query every single call.

_currentSettings is a `Dictionary<Type, Func<string, DataObject>>`

Comment: You should include the actual error, and the relevant code (e.g. what is _currentSettings). But you cannot use T like that, just like you wouldn't be able to use any type like that. If _currentSettings is indexed by type do typeof(T) instead. Otherwise provide more detail.

Comment: What type of object is `_currentSettings`?  It's also kind of unclear what you're trying to do ...

Comment: Sorry yes it is Keyed by Type. Your solution fixed it thank you.